# How to use ASP.NET authentication with active directory?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, active-directory

I have my config setup like below:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://myldap/CN=Users,DC=nevco,DC=local"/>
  </connectionStrings>
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" timeout="10" loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" />
</authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="DomainLoginMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="DomainLoginMembershipProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
      </providers>
     </membership>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I can attempt to log on but every time it says I am using the incorrect username/password.  Does it look like I am doing anything wrong above?  Is there any way for me to find more information on why it's not finding my username/pass?

**UPDATE:**

Do I need to provide a Username and Password in my membership/providers section?

Comment: What happens if you use `LDAP://myldap/`

Comment: It errors out with `The specified connection string does not represent a valid LDAP adspath.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I ended up using an LDAP browser to examine the structure.  After a little fudging around I changed my LDAP url to this:

```
LDAP://myldap/DC=nevco,DC=local
```

And it started working.  Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Why make the user login in at all?

Try this provider

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
```

you can then do something to see if they are authorized [Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z6b5d42.aspx).

```
Roles.IsUserInRole("someGroupInAd")
```

Your web site would have to be setup with [Integrated Windows Authentication](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5f8fe119-4095-4094-bba5-7dec361c7afe.mspx?mfr=true) in IIS

Comment: So this would use whatever windows account they are signed in with to access the site?  What if they were accessing form their home machine?

Comment: This would work if someone was connected to the domain.  Like an intranet site.  It probably won't work as a public facing website as you would have to have to setup the website to use anonymous access.